# Hoow in PhpStorm to set indents of code in 4 spaces?

Tags: phpstorm

In My PhpStorm 2019.2.5 with vue project how can I set indents of code in 4 spaces(without tab) ?
I have default settings in Settings=>Edito=>Copyright=>Formatting=>Vue.

and .eslintrc.js :

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    '@vue/standard'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'semi': 'off',
    'promise/param-names': 'off',
    'dot-notation': 'off',
    'no-trailing-spaces': 'off',
    'prefer-const': 'off',
    'space-before-function-paren': 'off',
    'space-in-parens': 'off',
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
    'comma-dangle': 'off',
    'object-curly-spacing': 'off',
    'vue/no-unused-components': 'off',
    'indent': 'off'
  }
}
```

This option must be also used in

```
Code=>Reformat Code
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: could you clarify what options you refer to? there are no code style settings for Vue in  PhpStorm 2019.2.5 (it uses HTML code style preferences for Vue templates formatting), neither it has **Editor | Copyright | Formatting** page in settings...

Comment: I mean this https://imgur.com/a/bcgMpsk option. Did I described path invalid ?

Comment: these settings only affect copywrite comments formatting... and you would like to format your Vue templates, right?

Comment: Looks like that is the only Vue item under my Settings?  Have I to activate some option additively ?

Comment: As I wrote above,  there are no code style settings for Vue in PhpStorm 2019.2.5, it uses HTML code style preferences (**Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML**) for Vue templates formatting. A dedicated section for Vue code style settings is available since version 2020.2, see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2020/07/webstorm-2020-2/#frameworks_and_technologies

Comment: Yes, I found this option and it has 4 indent value. But This value does not work for my new @vue/cli 4.5.8 app . Is it option common for all applications?

Comment: haven't got what you mean, sorry. Please check what indent size is chosen for your new app

Comment: Where have I to check what indent size is chosen for my new app ? PhpStorm options or .eslintrc.js ?

Comment: in your project settings - **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML**

Comment: As I wrote above I found this option and it has 4 indent value. Are there some place where some rules can be applied to vue files or all current project?

Comment: code style schemes can be either project-level or IDE-level, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.2/settings-code-style.html#scheme; the latter are applied to all projects